# ArrayIndexOutofBounds -- help?

Tags: java

The problem is at `int [][]tam = new int [a][b]`. It's only that line. I am new to Java and coming from a C++ background.

```
//"Exercitiul" 3
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);//instructiune scanner
DataInputStream dis4 = new DataInputStream(System.in);
DataInputStream dis5 = new DataInputStream(System.in);
String st1 = null;
String st2 = null;
try{
  System.out.println("Introduceti numarul de Randuri"); 
  st1 = dis4.readLine();
  System.out.println("Introduceti numarul de Coloane"); 
  st2 = dis5.readLine();
}

catch (IOException ioe) {
ioe.printStackTrace();
}

int a = Integer.parseInt(st1);
int b = Integer.parseInt(st2);

int [][]tam = new int[a][b];

System.out.println("Verificare " + tam[a][b]);
System.out.println("Introduceti Elementele Matricei ");

for (int m=0 ; m < tam.length ; m++)
for  (int n=0 ; n < tam[i].length ; n++){

tam[m][n] = input.nextInt();//instructiune scanner
}

System.out.println("Matricea A: ");
for (int m=0 ; m < tam.length ; m++)
{     System.out.println();
    for  (int n=0 ; n < tam[i].length ; n++)
        System.out.print(tam[m][n]+" ");
          }

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
at Program.main(Program.java:95)
```

Comment: where does the i variable come from? shouldn't there be m at two places where it is used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If an array `a` has length `n`, the elements are `a[0]` through `a[n-1]`.
In your case, you allocated `tam` as an `int[a][b]` and the bottom-right element of the matrix is `tam[a-1][b-1]`.

Also I think you want `m` as an index in your inner loop `for (int n=0 ; n < tam[i].length ; n++)` instead of `i`.

Answer (score 1):

If that line is throwing the exception, it probably means that either a or b is <= 0. Check your input values.

Comment: i am giving it inputs larger than 0

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is rather at the line

```
System.out.println("Verificare " + tam[a][b]);
```

tam is initialized as `new int[a][b]`. This means its first index goes from 0 to a - 1, and its second index goes from 0 to b - 1. Array indices start at 0 in Java. So `tam[a][b]` is indeed out of the bounds.

Comment: even if i delete that line same thing happens t

Comment: Yes, because you have other errors later. The line where the exception occurs tell you where the error is, as does the answer from Vlad.